# is there any way to convert string with hypen into integer in java(Android sdk)

Tags: java, android-studio, type-conversion

I am trying below code to convert string into Int but it is showing exception

```
String ID = "37f6c80-2d5-44c-82f-0001a40cf4"
int boardid = Integer.parseInt(ID);
```

Exception is :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
```

I can handle exception by writing it in try and catch, but the problem is there any way I can convert it into int?

Comment: What integer is ```"37f6c80-2d5-44c-82f-0001a40cf4"``` supposed to be?

Comment: Looks like you've got 104 bits of information there.  How do you think a 32 bit data type is going to cope with that?

Comment: It would be very interesting if you could include the expected result in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Long` object type but not int for this data:

```
public Long numberify(String number) {
    Long result = Long.parseLong(number.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z|-]", ""));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of all the non-number characters with this regex pattern `ID = ID.replaceAll("\\D+","");` and you can then convert it into int with your `int boardid = Integer.parseInt(ID);`. I would probably go for long though.